# 64 bit integers or UUID V5 or 64 characters long UID(sha 256) for User Id (uid) generation?

Tags: mysql, web-services, web-applications, web

1. Which of the ways is better for generating unique IDs for users? 
   I am not developing a distributed system. So, is the use of UUID any helpful (future proofing?).
2. Also, How good is integer joins vs VARCHAR joins?
3. Or is a generation of 64 characters long UID(sha 256) better?
4. Finally, How good is storing username (unique) next to a message data posted by a user on the mysql table rather than the user id?

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL Performance Blog has an article listing a few reasons why using [UUIDs are bad](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/13/to-uuid-or-not-to-uuid/).

I think it covers 1+3.

For 2, see this [other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332300/is-there-a-real-performance-difference-between-int-and-varchar-primary-keys) on the subject.

For 4, common knowledge is to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) first, and de-normalize only if performance suffers.