# Why should I use primary ID's for associated tables

Tags: mysql, database, web

I've been reading through questions explaining why primary ID's should always be used in tables, especially if a record in one table needs to associate with a record in another table.
However in my case the table is one of users, so has a name field. Surely for associating I could just use the name of the users to associate with, or am I missing something.

Comment: whats happens when you have 2 users with the same name?

Comment: Are the names unique? Is the `name` a `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: They are unique, but are not primary keys, the recommendations on other questions seems to be to have an integer primary key.

Comment: yes, but that's not essential.  You want a unique value, and even if the values are unique now, whats happens if you get a user with the same name as an existing user?  You can uniquefy the new users name by appending a digit to it, buts that kind of hacky ....

Comment: @ennuikiller It's already built into the php front end that a user can't create an account with the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the main reasons why you should have a Primary ID is because it should be permanent value since it could be used for referencing foreign keys from the other tables.

You can use name provided that:

- There is a key defined on it. (*obviously, a Primary Key or a Unique Key*)
- It cannot be modified. You have stated in your question: *"..associating I could just use the name of the users to associate with.."*. What if you want to modify the name and there are already records that are depending on it?

Comment: you forgot to mention that if he uses name field he has to insure that it contains unique values

Comment: Given the fact that the name is probably going to be the users email they may well want to change it (I didn't think of that). So looks like I'll go down the unique name/email and primary integer route.

Comment: One more thing: [Is there a REAL performance difference between INT and VARCHAR primary keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332300/is-there-a-real-performance-difference-between-int-and-varchar-primary-keys)

Answer (score 0):

You could define name as primary key. The result: can not be two users with same name in your table. The DB engine find records faster when you search by name.

Or you could add an integer primary key. and make name field as unique. In this case the above two think is exists. And one other thing: if you search records by integer (id) the DB engine find more faster the records.

Comment: So having an integer primary key makes it faster at the very least?

Comment: yes, if you use this key in your code to identify entities, and in search in database table with `WHERE id=xxx`