# does it worth switching a PRIMARY KEY from the type NVARCHAR to the type INT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, query-performance

On our SQL SERVER 2008 R2 database we have an `COUNTRIES` referential table that contains countries. The `PRIMARY KEY` is a nvarchar column:

```
create table COUNTRIES(
   COUNTRY_ID nvarchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
   ... other columns
)
```

The primary key contains values like 'FR', 'GER', 'US', 'UK', etc. This table contains max. 20 rows.

We also have a `SALES` table containing sales data:

```
create table SALES(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY
    COUNTRY_ID nvarchar(50),
    PRODUCT_ID int,
    DATE datetime,
    UNITS decimal(18,2)        
    ... other columns
)
```

This sales table contains a column named `COUNTRY_ID`, also of type `nvarchar` (not a primary key). This table is much larger, containing around 20 million rows.

Inside our app, when querying on the `SALES` table, we filter almost every time on the `COUNTRY_ID`. Even like this it takes too long to perform most of aggregation queries (even with the proper indexes in place)

We're in a development phase to improve the query performance on the `SALES` table. My question is:

**Does it worth switching the `COUNTRY_ID` type from `nvarchar(50)` to the type `int`?** If  the column `COUNTRY_ID` is converted in both tables to the type `int`, can I expect a better performance when joining the two tables?

Comment: This is a potential [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332300/is-there-a-real-performance-difference-between-int-and-varchar-primary-keys).

Comment: @Scott - event if this is almost the same case, that question refers to MySQL, not to SQL Server. Some answers in there could match my case, but I was hoping to get some more technical answers specific to SQL Server (maybe some numbers also). I hope you guys won't close my question

Comment: An int will probably be faster when you have joins but on the other hand, having a semantic primary key may mean that you will often not even have to join in the country table since you can filter directly on the foreign key.

Comment: @alun - Thanks, I see your point. In my case I am thinking to get the INT values in a temp table before querying on the big table. I can then use this temp table for joining with the SALES

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would personally recommend changing `COUNTRY_ID` from `nvarchar(50)` to an `INT`. An int uses 4bytes of data and is usually quicker to `JOIN` than `VARCHAR`.

You can also check to see if the space used is reduced by using the `stored procedure sp_spaceused`

```
EXEC sp_spaceused 'TableName'
```

Comment: Thanks for `sp_spaceused`. I did some tests and I've gained only 101Mb on the space used by the data (1855488 KB vs 1751408 KB). Almost the same for the space occupied by the indexes (91 Mb difference). I guess from this point of view there is not much difference.

Comment: @Lucian - that's still a good amount of space to be saved. As the tables grow the space saved will become valuable.