# Which is better bigint or nvarchar in case of primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, key, sql-types

I need primary key for table bus which stores info like bus no , bus type , registration no etc. As we know bus no is itself unique and can be **primary key but its of datatype string** which **slow down searching** in table, So another possible solution is adding **auto increment field** of type int, but this will increase network data as every time I need to **select both bus no and bus id(auto incremented)** for user selection on winform. I need to know which approach is better or is there other better approach.

Table Schema Approach 1

```
bus no - nvarchar(10) (primary key)
bus registartion no - nvarchar(10)
```

Approach 2

```
Bus id - int (autoincremnted) (primary key)
Bus no - nvarchar(10)
bus registartion no - nvarchar(10)
```

Comment: Please provide schema proposal.

Comment: NEVER use NVARCHAR as a primary key.  If you think there's a lot of network traffic using INTs, can you imagine how much more there'd be using NVARCHAR?  Design your schema properly and you can minimize the traffic and increase performance.  BigInt shouldn't be needed for a PK either as you're never going to get that many buses :)

Comment: Your BUS table should be something like CREATE TABLE bus (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), BusName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, RegoNumber NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARKY KEY (ID)).  Then you ALWAYS use the ID number as your look up value.

Comment: Why `BIGINT`? `INT` is not enough? `MEDIUMINT` is not enough too? I doubt that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [does it worth switching a PRIMARY KEY from the type NVARCHAR to the type INT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469677/does-it-worth-switching-a-primary-key-from-the-type-nvarchar-to-the-type-int)

Answer (score 0):

- Numeric - not null - columns are always the best option for primary keys on database tables. The database engine can store, index and look them up in the most efficient way.
- Do not mind network traffic overhead. Simply do not query columns you do not need in your result set. Avoid SELECT * statements.
- If necessary, type conversions (e.g. Integer to String) can easily be done in your SELECT's or in your client program.

When modeling your database, it is a best practice to add a primary key column to every table in advance, even if you feel you do not need it. Give your primary key column a standardized name (tablename + 'id' is a common naming convention) and type (integer, uniqueidentifier) and stick with it. Do not mix integer, long, short and other data types, because it can only complicate joining of tables.

E.g. for your entity Bus:

- table name is Bus
- primary key name is BusId
- primary key type is Int