# MySQL Text Indexes

Tags: mysql

I am working with a very old MySQL database which uses Yes/No as flags and CA, US etc. for identifying countries rather than 1/0 and country ID.

These all have indexes.

Is this much of a hit on performance? There are a lot of records in this database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using proper indices it will not make much of a difference when it comes to performance. However, the bigger problem is that it will make data management harder since a state code could change, states could potentially merge or be split etc.

Some good points are being made in this old question on the same topic:

[Is there a REAL performance difference between INT and VARCHAR primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332300/is-there-a-real-performance-difference-between-int-and-varchar-primary-keys)

Comment: Thank you. We have some performance issues and wanted to eliminate this.

Comment: Checking for slow queries would be a good start if you think the database is the problem: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html