# Querying an object with pk vs custom object_id

Tags: django, database, query-optimization, django-queryset, database-performance

I have a model as shown below,

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    person_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
```

where the person_id is populated on save, which is a random hex string generated by `uuid`, which would look something like `'E4DC6C20BECA49E6817DB2365924B1EF'`

so my question is, in a database of a large magnitude of objects, does the queries

```
Person.objects.get(pk=10024)
```

(`pk`) vs (`person_id`)

```
Person.objects.get(person_id='E4DC6C20BECA49E6817DB2365924B1EF')
```

does any of the method has a performance advantage in a large scale of data?

I am not much aware of the database internals.

My database is postgresql

Comment: This looks relevant (for mysql, but there are some general comments in the answers): [Is there a REAL performance difference between INT and VARCHAR primary keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332300/is-there-a-real-performance-difference-between-int-and-varchar-primary-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get good performance from querying a column in a database, it needs to be indexed. The primary key column is indexed automatically (by definition), but your person_id one won't be; you should add `db_index=True` to the declaration, then make and run migrations.